# Problema al conectar mongodb con docker

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-data

He estado intentando levantar una aplicacion con Spring-boot y Docker con docker-compose y me da este error :

```
jlopez-container-web | 
jlopez-container-web | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
jlopez-container-web |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
jlopez-container-web |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
jlopez-container-web |  ... 3 common frames omitted
jlopez-container-web |
```

Tengo la impresion que tiene algo que ver con el localhost a la hora de levantar el contenedor pero no entiendo que ruta debería poner.

DockerFile

```
# FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# For Java 11, try this
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
WORKDIR /opt/app
ARG JAR_FILE=jlopez.jar

# cp spring-boot-web.jar /opt/app/app.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
# java -jar /opt/app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'jlopez-container'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: jlopez
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
      - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
  web:
    build : ./web
    container_name: 'jlopez-container-web'
    links :
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      authentication-database: admin
      database: jlopez
      username: admin
      password: admin
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
```

He estado probando con distintios tipos de configuraciones y no he conseguido ver donde esta fallando.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza como hostname de mongo el nombre del servicio en el docker compose, en tu caso `mongodb`:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      authentication-database: admin
      database: jlopez
      username: admin
      password: admin
      host: mongodb
      port: 27017
```

El uso de `link` está obsoleto (https://docs.docker.com/network/links/), dentro de un sistema levantado con docker-compose los contenedores pueden ser localizados utilizando el nombre que le pusimos en el descriptor al servicio.